# Date picker click event required instead of select

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I used a jQuery datepicker in my application.

```
$('#button').datepick({
    onSelect : showStartDate
});
```

in `datepick.js` they have written the code for `onselect:`

```
var onSelect = inst.get('onSelect');
if (onSelect && !keyUp) {
    inst.inSelect = true; // Prevent endless loops
onSelect.apply(target, [inst.selectedDates]);
}
```

Now I want to change that to `OnClick` event only.
Any help??

Comment: which jquery datepicker plugin are you using? because the default jQuery UI calls `.datepicker()` not `.datepick()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation states that the [onSelect](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#event-onSelect) event:

> **"** Allows you to define your own event when the datepicker is selected. The function receives the selected date as text and the datepicker instance as parameters. this refers to the associated input field. **"**

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
       //create custom event to handle datepicker select
   }
});
```

If you are looking to make it so that the datepicker does not show unless it is clicked, you want to reference the [showOn](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-showOn) option.

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
    showOn: 'button'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just use

```
$('#button').click(function(){alert('clicked');});
```

What is it your trying to do? Handel the click on a date? or handel the click on the datePicket DOM element

Comment: hndle the click on the datepickr dom element.