# jQuery Datepicker - insert the data inside the input field when one of the date is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have some holidays days:

```
var holidayDays = ['24/12/2012', '2/1/2013', '14/2/2013'];
```

and code:

```
if( parseInt($("#date").val()) == holidayDays ) {  
        var freeday_value = ('holiday');
        $('#holiday_day').val(freeday_value);
    }
```

Who didn't work.

What I want to achieve: if in datepicker someone pick the date from above table, then on `input` field (`#holiday_day`) will be displayed word: holiday. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: var freeday_value=('holiday'); makes no sense

Comment: `holidayDays` is an array, you can't compare it to an integer value. It will always return false. And also what @specialscope said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check with [jQuery.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) function.

like

```
if( $.inArray($("#date").val(), holidayDays)>=0) {  
    var freeday_value = 'holiday';
    $('#holiday_day').val(freeday_value);
}
```

You should try this

```
var holidayDays = ['24/12/2012', '2/1/2013', '14/2/2013'];

$("#date").datepicker({"dateFormat":"dd/mm/yy", "onSelect":CheckForHoliday});

function CheckForHoliday(dateStr){
    if( $.inArray(dateStr, holidayDays)>=0) {  
        var freeday_value = 'holiday';
        $('#holiday_day').val(freeday_value);
    }else{
        $('#holiday_day').val('');
    }
}
```

Check This **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VyThg/3/)**

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing has changed

Comment: @Adrian maybe it's because the date format in your `datepicker` is different.

Comment: @Adrian, you should initialize datepicker with  `$("#date").datepicker({"dateFormat":"dd/mm/yy"});`

Comment: Can I use `onSelect` two times in my code? here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/amarcinkowski/skYXz/

Comment: @Adrian, You jsfiddle is not correct, your second input id should "date_to", made a change and here is new http://jsfiddle.net/skYXz/3/ jsfiddle check it and made changes, which you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could do like this :

```
if( $.inArray($("#date").val(), holidayDays) ) {  
        var freeday_value = 'holiday'; // Just removed () from your code
        $('#holiday_day').val(freeday_value);
    }
```

And Use [.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) to Compare in `if ()` condition

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing has changed

Comment: Have you tried .inArray in your code. I think your problem is in your condition "parseInt($("#date").val()) == holidayDays"

Comment: @Adrian, I have updated my code as per my understanding in your problem

Comment: Yes, a have tried with `if( $.inArray($("#date").val()) == holidayDays)`

Comment: @Adrian, don't use == but use , as in my answer

Comment: I corect the code, and now script insert on start holiday into input field, but when I change date, the phrase is still there.

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle for your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $.inArray($("#date").val(), holidayDays) ) {  
  $('#holiday_day').val('holiday');
}
else{
 $('#holiday_day').val(''); 
}
```

Comment: This code insert on start `holiday` into `input` field, but whe I change date, the phrase is still there.

Comment: Use onSelect: event of jquery ui datepicker (not ready or load of document). for your reference please check following link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481779/date-picker-click-event-required-instead-of-select